# Why my css is loading from the base theme instead of custom theme on migrating the site?

Tags: magento-1.7, css

I developed a site in magento on windows 7, and now my system has been updated and install an ubuntu 12.04 in it.

Now when I am running my site in browser I got an issue that my css is not loaded from the path which is loaded before.

Firstly my css path is like this

`http://127.0.0.1/magento/skin/frontend/default/sportation/css/style.css`

sportation is my custom theme, and now in ubuntu path is like this

`http://127.0.0.1/magento/skin/frontend/base/default/css/style.css`

Can anyone tell me why it is loading a css from the base theme I didn't understand, not only `style.css` every css is getting the path of the base theme.

My custom theme is still in working but not the css. How can I set the correct path.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure the rights and site owner are correct. the rights should be `664` and the owner should match your FTP username

Comment: I had already given full rights permission to my site, but not happening, and my site is on xampp server.

Comment: check the filenames, if it is on Windows developed, there might be uppercase/lowercase issues

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I have checked all the files, all are in lowercase. I really have no idea why it is not taking the path.

Comment: The magento default filename is `styleS.css` Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: You may have already done this but checking Apache logs can be EXTREMELY helpful in ruling out permissions, missing files, casing issues, etc. I'm not running Ubuntu or Xampp but I believe the logs would be stored within /opt/lampp/logs in your specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First clear the cache. It won't do you any good but do it anyway.
Then make sure that your theme is set to `sportation` under `System->Configuration->Design->Themes->Skin (Images / CSS)`.
Then make sure you don't have a custom theme set in `System->Design`.
Make sure the `style.css` from `sportation` exists and is readable.
Make sure your theme name does not contain uppercase letters. So `Sportation` works on Windows but it doesn't work on linux.

Comment: Thanks Marius I tried it, but doesn't do anything, still getting the base path. I also clear the `var/cache/`folder but no luck

Comment: I also tried the solution provide [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440854/css-doesnt-load-after-migration-of-magento-website?rq=1) except the first answer because I dont have .htaccess file in my root.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have merge CSS enabled

- Remove media/css and media/js directories (Same for the secure js_secure and css_secure

Make sure Media dir is writeable

Alternatively, turn off merge CSS
System > Merge CSS

It will revert to this basename if it is unable to access the files.

So check your permissions of directories and check your xml files. If it's just the CSS that's not loading then you may wish to check to see that it's spelt style.css in the xml

Answer (score 0):

You must need to check the PACKAGE which you are using that package info you will get form admin panel
system->configuration

select your store and go to WEB tab then check which package and theme you are using now. 
first change from that then clear CACHE and then try to refresh your page . It will appear to the front end side :)

Answer (score 0):

Change Permission Of Skin And Media  Containing **All Folder TO Give Permission 755** And **File TO 644**

Like
[image]